# How to properly increase AR.js processing resolution?

Tags: three.js, aframe, ar.js

I'm trying to increase the distance from which AR.js can detect a marker, using AFrame AR.js.

As I understand, the `sourceWidth` and `sourceHeight` determine which resolution is requested from the webcam, while `canvasWidth` and `canvasHeight` set the size for the canvas that ARController uses to process each frame.

The default width and height of both are set to 640 x 480, but changing either one requires changing the other as well, or the aspect ratio will not be correct anymore. However, different devices will have different aspect ratios especially for higher resolutions, and the rendering will get distorted.

The problem probably lies in having to define the canvas dimensions before having the webcam source dimensions. Is there a way to have the canvas dimensions set based on the initialized ARSource?

Or is there a different way to simply raise the resolution of the processing without worrying about supported resolutions and aspect ratios?

Comment: Hi Remix, struggling with the same issue did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: No, still haven't.